# Caused by: java.sql.SQLInvalidAuthorizationSpecException: Could not connect to address=(host=mariadb)(port=3306)(type=master) : (conn=6) Access denied

Tags: docker-compose, mariadb, access-denied

I am trying to bring up docker container using docker-compose up -d in Windows. But I am getting this error regarding connection issues with mariadb: **Caused by: java.sql.SQLInvalidAuthorizationSpecException: Could not connect to address=(host=mariadb)(port=3306)(type=master) : (conn=6) Access denied for user 'cataloguser'@'172.22.0.9' (using password: YES)**  I am not able to find out why exactly this is happening .

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on how to improve the quality of your question. Then check the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) to see what questions you can ask.

Answer (score -1):

You should share your docker-compose.yml for a better understanding of your configuration.
Anyway, ([doc network mode](https://github.com/compose-spec/compose-spec/blob/master/spec.md#network_mode)), you should try `network_mode: "host"` because your database authenticates an user from an IP. But in Docker, the Docker engine gives IP addresses in its "own subnet" ([doc here](https://docs.docker.com/network/)) that changes every time you rebuild the container. You can see it with  the `172.22.0.9`
So you should use the `network_mode: "host"` so the address you authorize in your database is localhost.

To answer your comment:

```
services:
  mssql:
    network_mode: host
    build:
      context: ./compose/mssql
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
    environment:
      ACCEPT_EULA: 'Y'
    env_file:
      - .env
    ports:
      - 1433:1433
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your suggestion....this network_mode: "host" ...Should be added after the docker compose up right?

Comment: Most applications should not need host networking.  This generally disables Docker's networking features, and you'll lose the ability to do things like run multiple copies of a database for multiple projects or services, or to run a private database that's only visible to other containers but not accessible from off-host.

Comment: Yes it is true. I don't see how to avoid this problem. Maybe OP could try to authorize cataloguser from the other container/service ?